# Get list of pending Celery jobs when no workers

Tags: python, django, celery

I think I must be missing something.  On my django server I do the following:

```
inspector = app.control.inspect()

for element in list:
    result = app.send_task("workerTasks.do_processing_task", args=[element, "spd"], queue="cloud")

scheduled = inspector.scheduled()
reserved = inspector.reserved()
active = inspector.active()

print("-- SCHEDULED")
print(scheduled)

print("-- RESERVED")
print(reserved)

print("-- ACTIVE")
print(active)

global_helper.execute_commands(["sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues"])

global_helper.execute_commands(["celery inspect active_queues"])
```

(excuse the printing, this is remote and I haven't set up remote debugging)

There are no workers connected to the server, and I get this output:

```
-- SCHEDULED
None
-- RESERVED
None
-- ACTIVE
None
     [  sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues  ]
Listing queues ...
     [  celery inspect active_queues  ]
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

So it looks like all of these tools require jobs to be on a worker somewhere.

So my question is, how can I look at tasks which are still waiting to be picked up by a worker?

(I have verified that app.send_task has been called 127 times)

Answer (score 0):

Celery does not provide this facility (probably there is a good reason for it) so you need to use your brokers facilities to find out what you want to know. Here is how for [Redis](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-redis-queues) and [RabbitMQ](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#inspecting-queues).